# Realm Change Listener with RealmResults not being called

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm 3.0.0

I'm fetching some objects from Realm and trying to add onChangeListener, but it does not get fired when an object is changed

Here's the code, am I missing something here?

```
 RealmResults<Record> realmResults = RealmManager.recordsDao().loadRecords();
    realmResults.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Record>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Record> element) {
            for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size(); i++) {
                if (collection.get(i).getId().equals(recordList.get(i).getId())) {
                    recordList.set(i, collection.get(i));
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Also as per the docs, it mentions to call `invalidateView();`
 but even that does not reflect the new data

The change to the object is made in the adapter

```
public class RecordsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Record> recordList;
private Context context;
private Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

public RecordsAdapter(ArrayList<Record> recordList, Context context) {
    this.recordList = recordList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_records, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.batsmanName.setText(recordList.get(position).getName());
    Glide.with(context).load(recordList.get(position).getImage()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(holder.profilePicture);
    holder.totalRuns.setText("Runs " + recordList.get(position).getTotalScore());
    holder.totalMatches.setText("Matches " +recordList.get(position).getMatchesPlayed());


    if (recordList.get(position).isFavourite())
        holder.favCheck.setChecked(true);
    else
        holder.favCheck.setChecked(false);


    holder.favCheck.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
                recordList.get(position).setFavourite(true);
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(recordList);
            });
        } else {
            realm.executeTransaction(realm12 -> {
                recordList.get(position).setFavourite(false);
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(recordList);
            });
        }

    });


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to store the RealmResults as a field reference in order to ensure that Realm can update it

```
RealmResults<Record> realmResults;

public void etc() {
    realmResults = RealmManager.recordsDao().loadRecords();
    realmResults.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Record>>() {
```

Also, you should probably use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters with `RealmResults<Record>`,  instead of `ArrayList` so that you actually keep a managed results in sync with your recycler view automatically

---

So with that in mind, all you need to do is replace your code with

```
public class RecordsAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViweAdapter<Record, RecordsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
     public RecordsAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Record> realmResults) {
         super(realmResults, true);
     }

     // ... same as before
}
```

and

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecordsAdapter(RealmManager.recordsDao().loadRecords());
```

And just ditch your `RealmChangeListener` because it is incomplete and unnecessary

Comment: Yes, using Realm Adapters made life simpler, BTW how do I convert an Arraylist<Record> to an OrderedRealmCollection<Record>

Comment: I'm getting this error -  This method is not supported by 'RealmResults' or 'OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot'

Comment: On Doing -  public void swapRecordList(ArrayList<Record> recordList) {
        OrderedRealmCollection<Record> recordRealmList = new RealmList<>();
        recordRealmList.addAll(recordList);
        realmResults.add(recordRealmList);
    }

Comment: you shouldn't have a `swapRecordList` method, just use `updateData`

Comment: again the problem here is, how do I convert my Arraylist<Record> to OrderedRealmCollection<Record> ?

Comment: Don't use ArrayList, use `RealmResults`, using `getData()` method of RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you saved my life, once again. Cheers, mate

Comment: everything work fine but recycler view does not scoll to bottom with android-adapters:2.1.1  and RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<MessageBean, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(messageBeans, autoUpdate) it it default behaviour for RealmResults @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I don't think adding new item ever scrolled to bottom without you manually doing that.

Comment: Life saver! I was declaring `RealmResults` inside onCreate. But after declaring them outside onCreate worked for me!